# How to format the writing of a numpy array in text file

Tags: arrays, numpy, txt

I'm writing a a large numpy array in a text file:

```
with open(f'C:/Path/Log_N_{N + 1}.txt', 'w') as log:
        log.write('snapshots_p: '+ snapshots_p_str + '\n')
```

It is working but I'm getting the output:

```
snapshots_p: [[16.26100465 16.26111114 16.26121829 ... 16.45950834 16.46117873
  16.46284186]
 [16.29273193 16.29283336 16.29293568 ... 16.50345694 16.50520892
  16.50695341]
 [16.32254644 16.32264219 16.32273902 ... 16.54403374 16.54585685
  16.54767231]
 ...
 [14.31230368 14.3087243  14.30534573 ... 19.57673369 19.57861486
  19.58044804]
 [14.74294061 14.72864507 14.71442799 ... 19.34044472 19.34912383
  19.35766631]
 [15.46559109 15.44851495 15.43140683 ... 18.61372907 18.63084135
  18.64782507]]
```

How can I adjust the line breaks in order to get the output:

```
snapshots_p: [[16.26100465 16.26111114 16.26121829 ... 16.45950834 16.46117873  16.46284186]
 [16.29273193 16.29283336 16.29293568 ... 16.50345694 16.50520892  16.50695341]
 [16.32254644 16.32264219 16.32273902 ... 16.54403374 16.54585685  16.54767231]
 ...
 [14.31230368 14.3087243  14.30534573 ... 19.57673369 19.57861486  19.58044804]
 [14.74294061 14.72864507 14.71442799 ... 19.34044472 19.34912383  19.35766631]
 [15.46559109 15.44851495 15.43140683 ... 18.61372907 18.63084135  18.64782507]]
```

Thanks.

I thought of using `\n`, but I don't know how to apply that in numpy arrays.

Comment: Have you looked at `np.savetxt`?